# How to improve efficiency of multiple JSON_EXTRACT SELECT expressions

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, json

In MariaDB + InnoDB, I have a table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `stuff` (                                                                                                                                             
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answers` longtext COMMENT 'JSON blob',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And `answers` stores a JSON blob like:

```json
{
  "aabbccddee": { "value": mixed, "meta": mixed },
  ...
}
```

Where `aabbddccee` is a short unique code that identifies the question to which the answer relates.

I'm extracting different multiple answers in a SELECT query using `JSON_EXTRACT` and I'm noticing that it's far slower than a PHP loop that goes through each one, decodes the JSON and extracts the relevant bits.

Example select:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(answers, '$.QIKhp7cTZYVIr.value') AS QIKhp7cTZYVIr,
  JSON_EXTRACT(answers, '$.Qaaaaaaaaaaaa.value') AS Qaaaaaaaaaaaa,
  ...
FROM answers;
```

I am imagining that the reason for this is that MariaDB is parsing the JSON *N* times where *N* is the number of SELECT expressions; whereas the PHP loop only parses it once.

Is there a way to get MariaDB to sort of get everything it needs from the JSON in one parse, and then separate it out into columns?

### EDIT

One non-answer to this is passing multiple params to `JSON_EXTRACT`: while this will extract multiple structures in a single pass (if found), it will return them in the order in which they're found in the JSON, not in the order you request them. So you can't correlate your inputs with your fetched data(!).

Comment: Use json_table to convert the json document to rows once, select what you need from that.

Comment: Do you think there's a way in MariaDB 10.3? JSON_TABLE was introduced in 10.6.

Comment: A database is optimized for indexed columns, not stuff squirreled away inside JSON strings.  Just because there are JSON functions to do a task does not mean they will be efficient.  It _may_ be more efficient for you to have another table that has the answer components, one per row.  (Plus appropriate INDEXes.)

Comment: @RickJames yep, agree. But I moved away from that trad solution deliberately for this particular use case as the bulk of the workload is more efficient this way.

Comment: There's no efficiency in JSON and the likes.  The only advantage is in avoiding to think things through before you start.